# How to eliminate duplicate values in dropdown of a React Table - ReactJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to learn multi filter with React Table. Here is my [Demo/Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2wjnz61l5)

I am trying to eliminate duplicate values in dropdown of my React Table

```
        <Select
          style={{ width: "50%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
          onChange={entry => {
            this.setState({ select2: entry });
            this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
              entry.map(o => {
                return o.value;
              }),
              "firstName"
            );
          }}
          value={this.state.select2}
          multi={true}
          options={this.state.data.map((o, i) => {
            return { id: i, value: o.firstName, label: o.firstName };
          })}
        />
```

I am getting  duplicate values in dropdown. Kindly help me how to eliminate the duplicate values in dropdown.

[image: Duplicate values in Dropdown]. As you can see Sam is coming twice.

[image: Screenshot 2]. Jones1 is also coming twice.

Basically  I am filtering each column and the above function basically deals with the filtering functionality. Kindly see the screenshot. There is the issue - there are some values which are multiple times in my Json array. But in the dropdown they should come only once.

**Edit 1 - I want to a generalized solution which can be applied to any number of dropdowns. Till now I have got two good answers. But both answers are not generalized. I want to extend this unique feature to all columns. I will have 15 to 20 columns. That is why I need a generalized solution.**

Comment: You're asking how to remove duplicates from a collection in JavaScript?

Comment: @Dave Newton Basically I am not aware of Collection. I am filtering each column and the above function basically deals with the filtering functionality. Kindly see the screenshot. There is the issue - there are some values which are multiple times in my Json array. But in the dropdown they should come only once.

Comment: Collection (noun): a group of things or people. My point is that you're basically asking how to filter a collection, which is covered all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var names = this.state.data.map((o, i) => {
  return o.firstName
})

var uniqueNames = names.filter(function(i, index){
    return names.indexOf(i) >= index
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/40n0jnzk5x
See fix for firstdropdown

Helper function

```
var uniqueOptions = (objectsArray, objectKey) => {

   var a = objectsArray.map((o, i) => {
     return o[objectKey]
   })

   return a.filter(function(i, index){
      return a.indexOf(i) >= index
   })
}
```

Usage for first name dropdown (Same for any other dropDown)

```
      ....
      multi={true}
      options={this.uniqueOptions(this.state.data, 'firstName').map((name, i) => {
        return { id: i, value: name, label: name };
      })}
      ...
```

Ideally, you would calculate this outside render to prevent recalculation on every render but you get the idea

Comment: Yes I understand your logic. But how can I use this in my Code. Can you please fork my fiddle and show me. There are two dropdowns. Please update my Sandbox and show how it works in my code. This is my fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/w2wjnz61l5

Comment: I want a generalized solution that will work for all fields like firstname, lastname. Your solution is only for firstname.

Comment: Apply the same for last name. You could write a function to address both at the same time but i think this is a more concise solution

Comment: Can we have a more generalized solution. See I have to basically 2 lines of code for every dropdown. If I have 15 columns have to write this again and again - var names = this.state.data.map((o, i) => {
  return o.firstName
})

Comment: Added a helper function you can use directly why setting your options

Comment: Can you please fork the fiddle and show me? Basically I want to have this for all columns. Kindly update the Fiddle/Sandbox and show how it works in my code. This is the fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/40n0jnzk5x

Comment: I have provided the full solution. The forum is for providing direction not completing code. Just add the uniqueOptions function to you class/component and use it on every drop down

Comment: Good Solution. Understood. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const getOptions = propertyName => {
  return this.state.data.reduce((accum, elem, i) => {
    const accumulator = [...accum];
    if (!accumulator.some(e => e.value === elem[propertyName])) {
      accumulator.push({
        id: i,
        value: elem[propertyName],
        label: elem[propertyName]
      });
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
};
```

`getOptions("FirstName")`

Comment: I want a generalized solution that will work for all fields like firstname, lastname. Your solution is only for firstname.

Comment: Can you please fork the fiddle and show me? Basically I want to have this for all columns. Kindly update the Fiddle/Sandbox and show how it works in my code. This is the fiddle -https://codesandbox.io/s/yvpq6lx4j1